# Random network hangs on macbook pro 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a Macbook Pro mid-2010 13" running latest updates of High Sierra.  The machine experiences random network hangs. This could be while browsing the web or copying files to a network share.  Firefox is used as the main browser, but closing it and using Chrome or Safari doesn't help.

One moment everything is fine, the next I can't connect to anything - I can't even ping the router or the WiFi access point. Disconnecting and reconnecting WiFi solves the issue - until it reappears again after some time.  If I simply let it sit once it happens, after some time it will "un-hang" and work again. Note that only network is affected - everything else works perfectly fine.

Furthermore, this only seems to affect WiFi. If I plug in ethernet cable, the issue doesn't show up.

I vaguely remember having this same problem with another machine (same mid-2010 Macbook Pro 13"), but can't remember how I solved it, as it's not having this issue now.

I can't pinpoint when this issue started, but fairly recently, maybe a month or two ago.  I have not installed any new software on it in at least a few months prior to the issue starting, except the usual MacOS updates and Firefox/Chrome updates.

How can I solve this problem?  Or at least how can I diagnose it?

Comment: Do you have this issue with any other devices?  A good test would be to see if the network hangs for all devices at the same time. If they do, then you know it’s your router. You can also try safe mode (Hold `Shift` while booting). It won’t load any 3rd party apps or kexts.  Use your computer normally (it may take some time). If it no longer hangs, something’s up with your OS.  Start there and post your results

Comment: Other devices are fine at the same time - so it's not router or WiFi access points. I'll do the digging in safe mode to see if I can find anything.